# Sylow subgroup of some factor group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $K$ be a subgroup of  $G$ and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$. Is $PN/N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $KN/N$?

Here is what I think.

Since $PN/N \cong P/(P \cap N)$, then $PN/N$ is a $p$-subgroup of $KN/N$.

Now $[KN/N:PN/N]=\frac{|KN|}{|N|} \frac{|N|}{|PN|}= \frac{|KN|}{|PN|}= \frac{|K||N|}{|K \cap N|} \frac{|P \cap N|}{|P||N|} = \frac{|K||P \cap N|}{|P||K \cap N|}=[K:P] \frac{|P \cap N|}{|K \cap N|}$.

Since $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$, then $p$ does not divide $[K:P]$. Also, $p$ does not divide $\frac{|P \cap N|}{|K \cap N|}$ as $\frac{|P \cap N|}{|K \cap N|} \leq 1$  because $P \cap N$ is a subgroup of $K \cap N$. Therefore $p$ does not divide $[KN/N:PN/N]$.

Thus $PN/N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $KN/N$.

Am I right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely persuaded by the last bit of your argument. Your assertion seems to be that if $a = b(c/d)$, where $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers and $c/d \leq 1$, and $p$ does not divide $b$ then it also does not divide $a$. But this is not true in general: take $a=2$, $b=3$, $c=2$, $d=3$, and $p = 2$.

But you can modify the argument as follows:

$P \cap N$ is a subgroup of $K \cap N$, so $|K \cap N| / |P \cap N|$ is an integer, call it $m$. Your equation 
$$[KN/N : PN / N] = [K : P]\frac{|P \cap N|}{|K \cap N|}$$
becomes
$$m[KN/N : PN/N]  = [K : P]$$
Now $p$ does not divide $[K:P]$, so it cannot divide either factor on the left hand side.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to my mistake. Things have become clear now. Thanks again.